# Laravel 5 Socialite Facebook Login Error handling on callback after user cancels app request

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have a Laravel 5 web app with Socialite to login my user by using Facebook account.

This is my callback function:

```
public function callback(SocialAccountService $service)
{

    $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());

    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect()->to('/home');
}
```

This is my SocialAccountService, basically the function returns the user if existing or creates a new one:

```
class SocialAccountService
{
    public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
    {
        $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider('facebook')
            ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {

            $account = new SocialAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'facebook'
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

            if (!$user) {

                $user = User::create([
                    'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                    'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                ]);
            }

            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();

            return $user;

        }

    }
}
```

Now the problem is, I am able to make my user login successfully via Facebook, but when the user clicks Cancel on the FB dialog for permission, it breaks.

[image: Callback Error on Facebook app permission denial]

How can I handle this error? I can see the error message in URL box, but don't know to handle them.

P.S I am fairly new to Laravel and Socialite

Comment: did you write routing properly?

Comment: `Route::get('/callback', 'SocialAuthController@callback');` This is the route I wrote, the user is able to login properly too, but if a new user cancels the permission dialog box, error occurs which I am unable to handle

Comment: you write routing for get method but I see here request come with post method

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/socialite see here details

Answer (score 9):

in the `callback(...)` method you can check for presense of the 'code' input field and if it is not there redirect to back to login page with errors.

Example:

```
function callback(SocialAccountService $service ,Request $request) {
    if (! $request->input('code')) {
        return redirect('login')->withErrors('Login failed: '.$request->input('error').' - '.$request->input('error_reason'));
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: I think input `error_reason` has been replaced by `error_description`.

Answer (score 2):

Try catch is the best practice(it catches all exception)

```
 try
{
    $userSocial =Socialite::driver('facebook')
    ->stateless()->user();
    dd($userSocial);
 }
catch (\Throwable $e) { 

//handle error here for php 7 or 8  

  } catch (\Exception $e) { 
  // for php 5
  handle error here 

  }
```